# Recovering Files Deleted From Local Repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

Let me get a couple things out of the way up front.

1. I'm very new at git. (I'm also new at everything else except Excel. Teaching myself "data science".)
2. Yes, I know the answer to my question probably appears 10^2s of times on SO. The truth is, I screwed up. I know/think I'm safe, so I'm not *freaking out*. But I am a little too stressed to spend a half day trying to find the right answer with clever search terms, and reading/trying/failing, then starting all over again. So I apologize for the no-doubt-duplicate question.

### WHAT I WANT TO DO

I have a bunch of source code in a private repo on Bitbucket. One output from running the code is a folder full of PDFs, as a subdirectory of the project directory. I wanted to give someone read-only access to only that directory. But you can't really do that.

### WHAT I DID

I committed all my local changes. Then pushed. Then I pulled from the remote origin just to make sure. Everything fine so far.

Next, I figured "I'll create a branch, and in that branch I'll only keep the folder of PDFs". (You **can** grant access to a specific *branch*, apparently.)

So I created a new branch, then switched to that branch (in my local IDE), selected all the files I did *not* want to share, and clicked delete. As soon as I did it, I went "d'oh!"

So now all the files on my local repo are gone. The remote origin, of course, is fine.

### WHERE I AM NOW

I just cloned the remote origin to my local drive, in a different location. So I think I'm fine there.

But:

1. how would I safely restore my work in its original location, just as it was when I last committed? Is it checkout? That's what bitbucket is prompting me to do....
2. what would be a good way to accomplish my original goal: granting access to specific content on a got repo? Workarounds OK, obviously.

   Thanks!

Comment: hmmm... it's not clear what exactly your IDE did.  from the commandline, run git status you will likely see that your editor did't commit the changes locally

Comment: no, the files are all gone! checked it at command line. anyway, the clone is now my new working copy, but I _still_ want to figure out how to give access to specific project content.

Comment: You can checkout to a particular commit. Do `git log -1`, copy the hash and do `git checkout <hash>`. Is this what you want?

Comment: if you did this in a branch, you can go back to the original branch from which the new branch was created, the files should be there.

Comment: Camilo & Hrishi - thanks. I think I'm going to have to go back a step or two and learn some more git basics. All I _really_ understand so far is "push" & "pull". Thanks for the tips; I'm sure when I learn more about checkouts (& branches) they'll make sense. Oh well. No shortcut this time!